# SQL MAX from multiple columns in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I need to fetch the maximum value from multiple columns in a single row.
The row looks like this:

```
Col1 || Col2 || Col3 || Col4 ||
100  || 120  || 130  || 140  ||
100  || 130  || 130  || 140  ||
100  || 140  || 130  || 140  ||
```

I need to fetch max of these columns where col2=120
so that the result is returned as col4 value which is 140

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This is using MSSQL Server

```
SELECT
  (
      SELECT Max(v) 
       FROM (VALUES (Col1), (Col2), (Col3),(Col4)) AS value(v) 
   ) as [MaxDate]
FROM [TableName] 
WHER Col2 = 120
```

Comment: What does 'value(v)' mean ? What kind of alias is that ?

Comment: Please add more details to this answer.

Comment: @CesarFlores i will leave that to the reader. Learning is not giving all answers. From the query, it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only 4 columns, one way would be to simply use case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Col1 >= Col2 AND Col1 >= Col3 AND Col1 >= Col4 THEN Col1
            WHEN Col2 >= Col1 AND Col2 >= Col3 AND Col2 >= Col4 THEN Col2
            WHEN Col3 >= Col1 AND Col3 >= Col2 AND Col3 >= Col4 THEN Col3
            WHEN Col4 >= Col1 AND Col4 >= Col2 AND Col4 >= Col3 THEN Col4
        END As Max
FROM TableName
WHERE Col2 = 120
```

Comment: As long as there are no NULL's in the table.

Comment: Any generic approach as its just an example, columns may vary for various tables